# Magento2 - php bin/magento setup:upgrade - Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: magento2, php, database, sql

Fairly new to `Magento`, I am trying to develop a custom module and have run the `CLI` command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`.

However I am getting the following error;

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`.

I have checked my `.env` file and granted all permission to the user on `phpmyadmin`.

I am on a `macOS` and using `MAMP`. Any advice or suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to check your privileges on the database : `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'localhost';`

Comment: @claims I have granted all privileges already on the database I am working with to the user

Comment: Check your db credentials in app/etc/env.php file. Are you able to login to mysql via command line using those credentials? If you are using MAMP on MAC, I believe you username: root and password: root should also work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you working in locahost try creating user and acess from root user  may be it help :

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'user';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
```

Try Reffering this [link](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-mysql-user-accounts-and-grant-privileges/)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have already tried this unfortunately :(